# ASP migration from asp webforms to asp netcore mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, migration

I am having a problem migrating a project from asp web forms to asp netcore mvc. Is there any advise or help? Also i need to take reports over to netcore. Will it be able to have report viewer in c#.

Still in the beginning stages